# Azure based method's completion code within an async code is not being executed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, grand-central-dispatch, azure-mobile-services

Here is a sample code -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                          NSArray* arr1 = @[newPost.postid];
                          [[LoginService defaultService].client
                           invokeAPI:@"GetPhoneNumbers"
                           body:arr1
                           HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                           parameters:nil
                           headers:nil
                           completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse* response, NSError* error)
                           {
                              .......
```

The dispatch_async is called from the main thread. Within the async code there is a  call made to a backend which has a completion block

In this code the completion block never gets called, no breakpoints are hit, no nslog gets printed.

I first thought that maybe because the thread that ran the async code is dying off without  waiting for the completion handler, and I tried with a infinite while loop to keep the thread alive and check, but that was not the case. Even then the completion handler is not called.

I tried to find examples which did something like this - call a method with a completion handler from within an async call, but couldn't find much material.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: It is most likely that your backend login service is not working and never calls the completion handler. Does invokeAPI return an error code if it does not run? You are not checking for any failures of that call?

Comment: Thats not it. There is error handling code within the completion block. I've tested this call direct from the main thread and it works fine.The moment i put it within a  "dispatch_async" the completion handler of this method stops being called.

Comment: And further investigation reveals that the moment i add this call within the "dispatch_async" code, the server side api is not even called when i checked from the server end. Calling directly from the main thread works fine.

Comment: When you call `invokeAPI`, does it return or get stuck on the method. If it gets stuck you should be able to pause the program and see where it is in the stack trace. If it is returning without calling the completion then it may be that it is designed to run on the main thread only for UI or other reasons? Does `invokeAPI` have a return type or is it void?

Comment: The method returns fine, without a problem.But I agree with you and am investigating this method more but this is a method within the Azure Mobile Services framework library..so maybe something funky going on in there. I think I'll update the tags to include azure folks also.

Comment: The azure SDKs are [open sourced](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services), so you can build it yourself and step into the api call to debug it and see what it is upset about.

Comment: I would NSLog all the parameters before the call to check they are all what you expect. Had a look at the open source and from that it looks like it should always call the completion handler.

Comment: What version of the SDK do you have? It looks like this issue was fixed last July but didn't make it into an SDK release until 1.2.4 in September. https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/pull/313  +1 for building the SDK from source.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the github details. This is the version i gathered from the files -

 #define WindowsAzureMobileServicesSdkMajorVersion 1

#define WindowsAzureMobileServicesSdkMinorVersion 2

#define WindowsAzureMobileServicesSdkBuildVersion 20910

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Xcode, don't know if this the correct version number i shared. Eric do you think this build number I shared could be pre-1.2.4, nomenclature suggests it should be ? This is a framework i had picked up through the quick start sample a.f.a.i remember.